# Mapping between doubly connected regions

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Suppose we have two annuli. The only way to have conformal map between them is to have same radius ratio.

Now lets take two annuli A(1,2) and A(1,8). I want to prove that conformal map between two these annuli cant happen  using contradiction. So suppose i apply iteratively reflection principle. And eventually will get to 0. Since its bounded its a removable singularity.

Now how i conclude contradiction from here? What condition is not satisfied that stops this conformal map?

Comment: Please write the explicit statement that you are trying to prove, it's not clear to me what that statement is.

Comment: I edited it. Want to show that no conformal map exists between those two annuli